# Converted posts to a CPT, 301 redirects necessary?

Tags: redirect

I had about 300 posts, sitting inside of the default post post type. I have since created two seperate CPTs, and transferred those posts to the new CPT's.

Do I need to set up 301 redirects for these posts? and if so what would be the most efficient way?

Thanks.

Comment: Do the URLs to the old posts redirect to the new ones? Some of these types of changes are handled automatically.

Comment: They do. They apparently do not need a 301 redirect. My client forgot that he had embedded links to each post into separate posts. So locating the broken links embedded in other posts was a pain in the ass. I thought the permalinks were broken, based on what he was explaining to me, but instead it was outbound links to those newly converted posts.

Comment: You can use something like HTTPFox to verify the 303 status.

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to check it out. Thanks @s_ha_dum